# International reward for filling in a survey

Tags: surveys

To motivate people to fill in our UX research survey we thought of giving a way a price. Now the problem is that the survey is global. Any physical prices are out of the question since this would really complicate things. We were thinking of Amazon gift cards but Amazon is mostly used in the US.

What would be a good (digital) price to give away internationally?

Comment: This isn't really a UX question. You've already solved the User Experience issue here (i.e. you have decided to motivate people to complete the survey with a reward). Deciding what that reward is isn't a UX question.

Comment: Hey Jon, yeah I was a bit in doubt to put it on here. But I thought since it was a UX survey it's related to this community. Any suggestions to where I could ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

See this previous [question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/122819/incentives-for-international-studies/122820#122820), as sounds similar. There I recommended using a crypo-currency like bitcoins as the prize.